# Autofill record when option from dropdown is selected

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm creating an Access DB tool to centralize some administration work for two teams. I work for a company that creates examens.

In my database I have several tables. But the two relevant tables are one where I list all the exams and one where I list all the subjects.

Table exams
Table subjects (relevant columns in this story: subject and type)

In the table of subjects there are three colums. One for ID, one for the subject itself and one for the kind of subject. (Oral exam, written exam...)

Example data

1 - Oral English - Oral
2 - Written French - Written
3 - Computer Science - Pratical
4 - History - Written

So, in the table of exams, I was able to link it succesfully with the table of subjects. But I'm able to create mismatches.

So, I can say that oral english is a written exam.

Is there a way to prevent this? So, that Access gives an error when I put something in the exam table that doesn't match the subject table? Or can I somehow autofill the type column when I enter the subject in the exam table?

I hope I explained the issue clearly enough, if there are any questions, feel free to ask me. I'm using Access 2013 in this project

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do (to me at least). Can you give the schema of the two tables, how you're linking them and what the expected results should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the question 3 times, I figured what you wanted is to autofill a control (i.e. textbox) based on the pick of a combobox.
To make it so, your combo's property **`limit to list` should be set to yes**.

To make it impossible for users to type wrong types of exam, like selecting English and writing Practice Exam, the textbox containing **ExamType, locked's property must be set to true.**
Then on the **Combobox (Dropdown) Afterupdate event**, you must insert the code below to search automagically for the Type of exam:

```
 textboxExamType.value = Dlookup("[KindofSubject]","TableSubjects","[Subject]='" & comboboxExam.Text & "'")
```

You will have to adjust the names of the controls and fields, because you did not provide them. Next time first read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)